# Counting tweet number with Tweepy issue

Tags: tweepy, twitterapi-python

i have got Researchers developer access in Twitter and I need to execute the code which would count daily number of tweets by keywords. I have the code below:

```
import tweepy
from twitter_authentication import bearer_token
import time
import pandas as pd
name_data = pd.read_csv('name_data.csv', header='infer')
name_id_data = name_data[["business_id","business_name","date_rev"]]
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
count_tweets = []
for response in tweepy.Paginator(client.get_all_tweets_count,
                                 query = 'Covax lang:en',
                                 granularity = 'day',
                                 start_time = '2021-01-20T00:00:00Z',
                                 end_time = '2021-02-21T00:00:00Z',
                                 pagination_token=None):
        print(response)
```

However, the problem is that python gives me the following error:

```
The query parameter [pagination_token] is not one of [query,start_time,end_time,since_id,until_id,next_token,granularity,search_count.fields]
```

I tried to use tweepy.Cursor() as well but it states that this method does not support pagination. Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Pagination token is not an argument for get_all_tweets_count() method.

````
Client.get_all_tweets_count(query, *, end_time, granularity, next_token, since_id, start_time, until_id)```

Please remove that and and try
````

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this did not work either. I think this has something to do with Paginator method, but still cannot understand what.

Comment: ohh. I don't have a research account to test it out. Hope someone will help you to find the answer :)